# SQL query to merge rows based upon sequence defined

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables `TableA` and `TableB`, here is data of both tables

```
OrderNumber LineSEQNo   SequenceNumber  CommentText
2145106     0000000001      000           ABB -
2145106     0000000001      001           2" AL. pole 7'8"
```

And TableB as below

```
    SalesOrderNumber    LineSEQNo       desc1           desc2
      2145106           0000000001      ORDER DIDN't     NULL
      2145106           0000000002      ABB              BCC                                      
      2145106           0000000003      NULL             Customer did NOT get any.
```

Now I want output from `TableB`.. I mean output should have same count as `TableB` have..

1. There will be one `LineSEQNo` (distinct) per row of table
2. `TableB.LineSEQNo` will check in `TableA` for that `LineSEQNo`. If it exists in `TableA`, then the `SequenceNumber` for that `LineSEQNo` will be shown and merge `CommentText` in one row based upon sequence.
3. If that `LineSEQNo` does not exist in `TableA`, then `desc1` and `desc2` will be concatenated for that `LineSEQNo`

So output should look like this:

```
2145106 0000000001      ABB - 2" AL. pole 7'8"
2145106 0000000002      ABB BCC
2145106 0000000003      Customer did NOT get any.
```

Hope I made it clear.

Now for solution only solution that is coming in my kind is `WHILE` loop..

Is there any other way I can get this desired result without a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hard part is concatenating the strings for tablea.  You can do this in a subquery and then use `left join` and finish the logic with a `coalesce()`:

```
select b.*,
       coalesce(a.commenttext, coalesce(desc1, '') + coalesce(desc2, '')       
from tableb b left join
     (select a.ordernumber, a.lineseqno,
             (select a2.commenttext as commenttext
              from tablea a2
              where a2.ordernumber = a.ordernumber and a2.lineseqno = a.lineseqno
              for xml path (''), TYPE
             ).value('.[1]', N'varchar(max)') as commenttext
      from tablea a
      group by a.ordernumber, a.lineseqno 
     ) a
     on b.ordernumber = a.ordernumber and b.lineseqno = a.lineseqno;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/904) is a SQL Fiddle that shows the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks For ur help everything is working perfect except that Text from TABLE A .. has is showing up with <CommentText> then comments </CommentText> ??

Comment: @spenzo . . . I fixed the `for xml path()`.  Admittedly, I tend to use `('')`.  However, the right method is to assign a type and get the value.  Note that you should use `nvarchar()` if that is the type of your field.  This also protects against weirdness such as "&" being turned in "&amp.".

Comment: @Spenzo . . . A mistake made by wishful programming.  I always think of `TYPE` as being an "argument" to the `PATH` construct.  In reality, it is a modifier to `FOR XML PATH`.  The former always leads me to mess up the syntax, until I look it up, then I look it up and then get it right.